# Deploying laravel 4, class not found

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

Im trying to deploy laravel 4 on a shared host. When I do so and trying to run the site I get an error saying :

> Class 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider' not found

I guess this has something to do with composer, I have read a lot and some say that I should run 'composer dump-auto' on the server, I can't do that because I have no shell-access.

Other say I should run composer update locally and then upload it and it should all be fine. That does not work either.

Any ideas how I should approach this?

Comment: Have you spoken to your hosting provider?

Comment: just asked if they support ssh, do think it's a problem with their servers?

Comment: I suppose it depends if your plan allows Ssh access

Comment: I used another hosting provider and it worked there without updating composer. So the problem laid with the provider